# simplest usecase of cy.request is not working

Tags: cypress

I have following code:

```
    cy.server();
    cy.route({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'http://localhost:4200/api/login',
        response:{sadasda:2312312123}})
    cy.visit('http://localhost:4200/');
    cy.request('GET', '/api/login');
```

But cy.request throws 404 error. Pls see the screenshot below. What am i doing wrong?

---

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs for `cy.request`](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/request.html#cy-request-cannot-be-used-to-debug-and):

> cy.request() cannot be used to debug cy.server() and cy.route()
>
> cy.request() sends requests to actual endpoints, bypassing those defined using cy.route()
>
> The intention of cy.request() is to be used for checking endpoints on an actual, running server without having to start the front end application.

`cy.route()` is intended to be used to test your application, not to test `cy.request()`. Try making an XmlHttpRequest from your application that matches the `cy.route()` like so and it will work:

```js
const xhr = new XmlHttpRequest()
xhr.open('GET', 'http://localhost:4200/api/login', false)
xhr.send() // now your `cy.route` will trigger
```